# Discord.js || Can bot track ban list?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

There are a lot of to ban a user in a server, you can do it manually or with another bot. I want my bot to scan a `banlist`, and if someone will get banned, it will send a message "user (id) has been banned

I started writing smt but now, I had no idea what can I do to check it.
EDIT: It's working now, but it still need to find this user id.

```
client.on('guildBanAdd', message => {
  client.user.cache.find() //idk how to define it
  const channel1 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "158751278127895");
  channel1.send('12512');
  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to fetch bans because the [`guildBanAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd) event parses a [`GuildBan`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildBan) object,
which als includes a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) object.

```
client.on('guildBanAdd', ban => {
    console.log(ban.user.username); // Username
})
```

- `message.channel` won't work because there isn't a message object.

If you want to get the executor (moderator) who performed the ban, kick etc.
There is a good guide for this [`Working with Audit Logs`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#some-quick-background)